# Using Weather-Icons(erikflowers) in React

Tags: reactjs, icons

Hi guys I'm trying to figure out how to use these icons by Erik Flower in my React app. I am using openweather api to get the data and I am trying use these icons.
I am trying to implement this code in axios request.
But for some reason its not working.

```
 req.then(function(resp) {
  var prefix = 'wi wi-';
  var code = resp.weather[0].id;
  var icon = weatherIcons[code].icon;

  // If we are not in the ranges mentioned above, add a day/night prefix.
  if (!(code > 699 && code < 800) && !(code > 899 && code < 1000)) {
    icon = 'day-' + icon;
  }

  // Finally tack on the prefix.
  icon = prefix + icon;
});
```

can anyone help me out please?